# C++ check if lamda takes parameters

Tags: c++

I have a class hierarchy of operations like plus, minus, e.t.c. I pass an object **f_** that accumulates lambdas in it. So if there any lambda that takes these params then it'd be called otherwise default implementation of a child'd be called.

How to check that lambda takes arguments of types T1 and T2?

```
    Value* operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
        if (std::is_same_v<decltype(f_(t1, t2)), Value*>)
            return f_(t1, t2);
        else
            return static_cast<Impl<Func, TypePairs<Head, Args...>>*>(this)->run(std::move(t1), std::move(t2));
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to allow implicit conversion, or only an exact match?

Comment: @Useless exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f_), T1, T2>) {
        return f_(t1, t2);
    }
```

[In addition, you can check if it returns a particular type or throws exceptions.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable)

Answer (score 0):

The below code ensures that implicit conversions will not be performed:

```
struct Value{};

template<class F, class T1, class T2>
using Ptr = Value* (F::*)(T1,T2) const;

template<class,class,class,class=void>
struct Checker : std::false_type {};

template<class F, class T1, class T2>
struct Checker<F,T1,T2,
   std::void_t<
       decltype( std::declval< Ptr<F,T1,T2>& >() = &F::operator() ) > 
       > : std::true_type {};
```

the use:

```
template<class F, class T1, class T2>
void bar(F f, T1, T2) {
    if constexpr ( Checker<F,T1,T2>() )
        std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto l = [](int,float) { return new Value{}; };
    auto l2 = [](double,float) { return new Value{}; };

    bar(l,10,10.f); // (int,float) done
    bar(l,10,10); // (int,int) failed
    bar(l2,20.,34.f); // (double,float) done
    bar(l2,10,10); // (int,int) failed
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MpcFDU)

---

Some remarks

Lambda expression generates closure which has `operator()` defined as *const* method.
The check `std::declval< Ptr<F,T1,T2>& >() = &F::operator()` is used to guarantee that input type paramters `T1`,`T2` are matched without any implicit conversions to parameters of function call operator.